# how to get compiled element in custom directive compile function

Tags: angularjs

I have used angular JS custom directive **compile function**, in that I am not able to get the compiled HTML element. I am getting-

```
<div id="test_{{value}}" modulename="test_{{value}}"></div>
```

How to get the compiled html element in Post link method?
like this,

```
<div id="test_1" modulename="test_1"></div>
```

compile function code as follows,

```
module.directive("custom", ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'CEA',
            transclude:true,
            compile: function(el) {
                if (settings.require && settings.require.length) {
                    return function(scope, el) {
                        $compile(el)(scope);
                    }                        
                }
                return {
                    pre: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {

                    },
                    post: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
                        //here need to get compiled html element
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It gets compiled in compile function. How would you get it already compiled in compile?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you show your directive code as well?

Comment: @tanmay i need to get compiled element in link pre or post method

Comment: @nikjohn i have updated the question could you pls check on this

Comment: What I meant was your _entire_ directive.